# How to set session.save_path value when installing mediawiki 1.16.5

Tags: php, mysql, session, mediawiki

I'm replacing an older version of mediawiki and installing mediawiki 1.16.5, but I was presented with the following warning:

"Warning: Your session.save_path value (C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp) appears to be invalid or is not writable. PHP needs to be able to save data to this location for correct session operation."

I continued with the installation anyway and it caused various problems; mediawiki is very slow, and when I edit a page and save, an error telling me the same as above is displayed at the bottom of the page.

I've checked the path and the 'temp' folder is read-only. If I un-check the read-only option and apply it, it returns to read-only. I'm not quite sure what to do, since the older version of mediawiki worked fine before with the folder settings this way.

I'm having a total brain-fart today, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot help you with folder privileges under Windows.
But you can simply find your appropriate php.ini (check output of phpinfo() if in doubt), find some folder which is world writable (or at least writable for the webserver) and add/replace

```
session.save_path=C:/path/to/folder
```

there. You will have to restart the webserver for this to take affect.

When using mod_php with apache you can also put the line

```
php_value session.save_path=C:/path/to/folder
```

into a .htaccess or into your (v)host definition in the httpd.conf. Not sure for other webserver/sapi.